# Could not find any url links in pagesource

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to find url links in pagesource for this website

```
http://data2.7m.cn/database/index_en.htm
```

but i could not find anything in pagesource or i also tried ajax calls with firebug but i could not find any links for eg(England,Italy,Germany....etc)

In deatil if you click england link i will take you to

```
http://data2.7m.cn/matches_data/92/en/index.shtml
```

But this link is not avaliable in original page

```
http://data2.7m.cn/database/index_en.htm
```

How could i find the like and where does it comes from via ajax calls are some other source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is coming from js the person has created a big array and appending result in page.

While reality is that view source never render's javascript so you can not view it or find it.

Here is the js from this date render's

http://data2.7m.cn/database/js/v2/matchdata.js

Comment: Is there any ways to extract those links?

Comment: person has done some smart work there is a number given to the image a tag and "/matches_data/"+93+"/en/index.shtml" for refrence 93 is changed . in view source you can see that data after line 123